# Provide my users with a realtime API using Pusher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server-push

I'm using [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) to add realtime functionality to my app. Is there a way to provide my users with realtime functionality through an API? I'm using private and presence channels, so connections to these need to be authenticated. Has anyone worked with Pusher and provided some sort of API to their users?

I'm doing this using Rails 3.1.

Comment: I'm a dev evangelist at Pusher. Are you trying to give your users access to your data on the client (web browser) via an API? Do you want them to be able to subscribe to your data (public/private channels) on their own site?

Comment: Kind of the first. I'd like to provide a real-time api so, for example, a [Hubot](http://hubot.github.com/) could connect and listen for messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is to give the users you want to be able to access your data your `app_key` (**not** `app_secret`). They can then connect to Pusher and try to subscribe to your channels. They'll need to use [`JSONP` authentication](http://blog.pusher.com/2010/10/26/jsonp-authentication-for-private-channels) which makes a call to your server where you can authenticate the request to the [private](http://pusher.com/docs/private_channels) or [presence channels](http://pusher.com/docs/presence).

```
Pusher.channel_auth_endpoint = 'http://yourserver.com/pusher_jsonp_auth';
Pusher.channel_auth_transport = 'jsonp';
var pusher = new Pusher('YOUR_APP_KEY');
var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-your-channel');
channel.bind('your_event', function(data) {
  // do something here with data
});
```

In your authentication you'll need to check the referrer (domain) to see if you've given them access to your data along with what they are subscribing to.

You could also wrap this JavaScript up in your own library so that a [`subscription_error`](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_channels#auth-problems) (authentication error) disconnects the client from Pusher.

Hope this helps. You can always drop an email to support@pusher.com too.